# Using collection inside dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, numbers, dynamic-sql

I am trying to pass dbms_sql.number_table from one procedure to another and then using it inside a dynamic plsql block. But the below code throws error as:

> Error(6,17): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

```
create or replace
procedure proc1( v_in_table_name varchar2,
                 v_in_column_name varchar2,
                 v_in dbms_sql.number_table)
as
plsql_block varchar2(4000);
begin
   plsql_block:='declare

                 begin
                      FORALL INDX IN 1 ..'||v_in.count||'  SAVE EXCEPTIONS 
                       UPDATE '||v_in_table_name||'
                         Set '||v_in_column_name||'=123 WHERE col2='||v_in||'(INDX)||;
                 end';
    execute immediate plsql_block;
end proc1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make two changes: 
First(and its case of error) its when you concatinate string with collection. 
If you want to send collection into pl/sql block you shoud use the param.
And second you should add `;` in the end of dynamic pl\sql:

```
create or replace
procedure proc1(v_in dbms_sql.number_table)
as
plsql_block varchar2(4000);
begin
   plsql_block:='declare
                   l_collect dbms_sql.number_table := :number_table ;
                 begin
                      FORALL INDX IN 1 ..'||v_in.count||'  SAVE EXCEPTIONS 
                       UPDATE table_name
                         Set col1=123 WHERE col2=l_collect(INDX);
                 end;';
    execute immediate plsql_block using v_in;
end proc1;
```

But after all changes I would like to ask: Are you realy need to use dynamic pl\sql?

Comment: Not sure where have you tried coz i have oracle 11gR2 and it gives me this error `PLS-00457: expressions have to be of SQL types` . I would say try again and post the working version

Comment: getting this error while compiling Error(13,41): PLS-00457: expressions have to be of SQL types

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using a dynamic block. Also i dont think it can work as well. You can use this way;

```
create or replace
procedure proc1(v_in dbms_sql.number_table)
as
plsql_block varchar2(4000);

l_collect dbms_sql.number_table;

begin

l_collect := v_in;

 FORALL INDX IN 1 ..l_collect.count  SAVE EXCEPTIONS 
      UPDATE table_name
    Set col1=123 
    WHERE col2=l_collect(INDX);

 commit; 
end proc1;
```

Execution:

```
 SQL> DECLARE
       var   DBMS_SQL.number_table;
       BEGIN
         var (1) := 1;
         var (2) := 2;
         var (3) := 3;
        proc1 (var);
       END;    
     /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

EDIT: As per your edit the code becomes like:

```
 create or replace procedure proc1 (v_in_table_name     varchar2,
                                   v_in_column_name    varchar2,
                                   v_in                dbms_sql.number_table)
as
   plsql_block   varchar2 (4000);
begin
   plsql_block := q'[ FORALL INDX IN 1 ..v_in.count  SAVE EXCEPTIONS 
                          UPDATE :table_name
                          Set :col1=123 
                          WHERE col2=v_in(INDX)]';

   execute immediate plsql_block using v_in_table_name, v_in_column_name;

   commit;
end proc1;
```

Comment: I am doing some other processing inside dynamic plsql block so I need that for all inside a dynamic block.

Comment: You are just looping the data inside the collection. I am also doing the same. I am just coping the data to a variable and running it. The need of dynamic block is useless here

Comment: My requirement is such that I need to use a dynamic block

Comment: And wat you want to achieve using dynamic sql. Coz whatever you want to achieve that can be done using the above.

Comment: table name in the update statement is dynamic hence dynamic block

Comment: If tablename is dynamic when why we're you passing collection dynamically. From your example it doesn't show you that you want to pass table dynamically. What exactly are you trying to achieve..or you simply playing with all the options available in oracle.